# What is the difference beetwen bytecode and object code?

Tags: java, .net, compiler-construction, virtual-machine, computer-science

I was read book algorithm for compiler design (2003), there is another variant compiler called cross-compiler that produce object code for multiple machine, but In another book i was read that there is exist code called bytecode that produced for multiple machine too but its executed via JIT compiler on virtual machine. java on JVM and .Net on CLR.

is object code and byte code are same? or different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byte Code is the Object Code of the JVM . They are the same is the answer to your question. They are the same in the sense that Byte Code is an object code. But, an object code isn't necessarly byte code. There are more explanations within the link below as this is a repeat question

(Edited)Oh and Apparently this is a repeat question:

[Does Java produce object code or byte code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934283/does-java-produce-object-code-or-byte-code)

Comment: Actually, there are a number of different "bytecode" instruction sets.  JVM Bytecodes, CLR & Davlik are well-known recent examples.  Wikipedia lists more than 30 of them

Comment: how about MSIL? are we can call it as bytecode too?

Comment: No.  It is not designed to be executed / interpreted directly. It is described as a form of assembly language, not a machine language.

Comment: They are similar but I dont think u can call MSIL bytecode. Im not 100% positive about MSIL

Comment: hmm thank you step and dark for the explanation (y)